# What is still missing in my attempt to host a blazor-server app?

Tags: blazor-server-side, iis-8

I've been hitting my head against this wall for days now and to my knowledge I've followed every direction I've found. But I'm still getting a 500 Error when I browse to the URL.

What I've got to work with is a Windows Server 2012 R2 with IIS 8.5. I'm not married to IIS but I'd prefer not to dip into YET another tech just to get this running.

#### What I've done:

- Old-style **blazor-server** app (with Program / Startup pair) without authentication. Dependencies:

  - SharpZipLib
  - LiteDB
- published it using `dotnet publish -o bin/publish --self-contained -r win7-x64`
- copied that folder to the server
- On the server:

  - installed `urlrewrite2`
  - installed everything under Windows Features `Word Wide Web Services` and `Web Management Tools`
  - restarted
- created a new site in IIS

  - set the application pool to `unmanaged`
  - set the physical path to the folder I copied from my dev system

#### What I haven't done:

Anything regarding **Visual Studio** as I'm currently forced to contend with **Visual Studio *Code*** and none of that applies/is possible here.

#### Provisional Workaround

- running `dotnet my.dll --urls http://*:1234` does work to expose the app to the network
- the command needed to be run inside the application folder otherwise the app would fail to load the connection string.
- I've also had to provision a production database and modify my `appsettings.json` accordingly

This is workable for now but not having the app "auto start" with the server is unsatisfactory.

Comment: Do you have any other error messages besides the 500 error? Maybe you can try to use failed request tracing to get detailed error information.

Comment: @samwu unfortunately not. I have been able to run the app via `dotnet my.dll --urls http://*:1234` now but it requires me to be logged into the server. Does that help narrow something down? That failed request tracing is not set up and sounds very involved!

Comment: About how to use  failed request tracing you can refer to this link: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules).